# NodeJS Ajax 404 file not found

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I am new to NodeJS. I have a login page and I am trying to validate a user using a form. So I am trapping the form submission and sending an ajax request to my server(app.js) file. However, what I get back from the server is 404- not found. I want to perform validation and if the user is verified take him to another page or else print the error message in the login page itself. I am not getting how to do this in node-js. And one more doubt, How to handle ajax requests and also HTTP requests for a page at the same time. Thank you.

Here is my client-side Javascript code that performs validation:

```
function checkUserParameters(username, password) {
var jsonObj= '{"username": \"'+username+'\", "password": \"'+password+'\"}'
jsonObj= JSON.parse(jsonObj)
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/login.html',
    type: 'post',
    data: jsonObj,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Obtained '+data+' data from server')
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log('Text status : '+textStatus+' Error: '+error)
    }
})
```

}

Here is the server (app.js) code:

```
const path= require('path')
const express= require('express')
const mongodb= require('mongodb')
const MongoClient= mongodb.MongoClient

const databaseURL= 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
const databseName= 'projektx'

const app= express()
const pathDir= path.join(__dirname, '../public')

app.use(express.static(pathDir))
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
    next()
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('./login.html')
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is up on port 3000")
})
```

Comment: Try by removing .html from link url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',

Comment: Then, try like res.render('./login.html')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `url` for your AJAX request does not match the path you expose to the Express `app.post` to `/login` endpoint.

You either need to change your AJAX request to `/login` rather than `/login.html`, or change the Express endpoint to be `/login.html`